# Replace multiple strings of text in a large dataframe in r

Tags: r, replace, network-programming, dataframe, gsub

I have been trying to use gsub to replace identifier keys with simple integers in an edgelist.  The edgelist is comprised of individuals and a list of their connections (variable length by individual). Unfortunately, since my dataset is over 300K rows (thereby requiring 300K+ search and replace operations), running it iteratively will take almost a week to run through.  The currently code is able to produce the desired output, but I'm attempting to find a more efficient method.  Does anyone know a better method for producing a similar output?  My current code, some hypothetical sample data, and the sample output are below:

Sample Data:

```
Person  Connection_list
ENJAK   IDFJA, FDAKD, AODMK
JBJDF   KJDFA
LAFMD   JBJDF, KAOJD, ENJAK,FKJSE,IDFJA, AKSKE, FNAFJ, KJDFA, ATNFN, ADOFA, ODIJA, AODMK, NAGJA, NFAKD, FDAKD, KDSFN
ADOFA   JDFKA, KAOJD, NAGJA
KJDFA   ENJAK, ATNFN, NFAKD, ADOFA, AODMK, JDFKA, LAFMD, ODIJA, FNAFJ, KDSFN, JBJDF, FJKAS, FKJSE, AKSKE, NAGJA
IDFJA   AKSKE, KJDFA, FJKAS, ADOFA
KDSFN   KAOJD, ADOFA, AKSKE, FDAKD, NFAKD, FKJSE, NAGJA, JDFKA, ODIJA, FJKAS, ATNFN, JBJDF, FNAFJ, KJDFA, LAFMD, ENJAK
AKSKE   ADOFA, ODIJA, KAOJD, JBJDF, ENJAK, AODMK, FDAKD, IDFJA, NAGJA, KJDFA
NAGJA   KAOJD, AKSKE
ODIJA   ADOFA, FDAKD, FKJSE, ATNFN, IDFJA, NAGJA, KAOJD
FKJSE   JBJDF, NAGJA, KDSFN, KAOJD, LAFMD, KJDFA, NFAKD, FDAKD, ENJAK, ATNFN, FNAFJ, ODIJA, ADOFA, AODMK, FJKAS, AKSKE, IDFJA
FDAKD   ADOFA, ODIJA, FKJSE, NAGJA, NFAKD, KJDFA, JBJDF, ATNFN, AODMK, AKSKE, KDSFN, JDFKA, LAFMD
NFAKD   ADOFA, KJDFA, AKSKE, KDSFN, FJKAS, JBJDF, JDFKA
FJKAS   FKJSE, AKSKE, FDAKD, NAGJA, ADOFA, ENJAK, FNAFJ, KDSFN, NFAKD, ATNFN, AODMK, KAOJD, JBJDF, JDFKA, LAFMD, IDFJA
JDFKA   AKSKE, KJDFA, IDFJA
ATNFN   AODMK, IDFJA, AKSKE
KAOJD   ENJAK, FJKAS, FKJSE, AKSKE, NFAKD, LAFMD, JDFKA, KDSFN, ODIJA
AODMK   AKSKE, FNAFJ, KAOJD, JDFKA, LAFMD, FDAKD, KDSFN, ENJAK, FJKAS, JBJDF, FKJSE, IDFJA, ATNFN
FNAFJ   JBJDF, ADOFA, NFAKD, ODIJA, KAOJD, FKJSE, LAFMD, AKSKE, KDSFN, IDFJA, FNAFJ, ENJAK
```

Current Code:

```
for (i in 1:dim(data)[1]){
  data$key[i] <- i
  data[,2] <- gsub(data[i,1],as.character(i),data[,2])
}
```

Desired/current output:

```
key  Person Connection_list
1   ENJAK   6,12,1,18
2   JBJDF   5
3   LAFMD   2,17,3,1,11,6,8,19,5,16,4,10,18,9,13,12,7
4   ADOFA   15,17,9,4
5   KJDFA   1,5,16,13,4,18,15,3,10,19,7,2,14,11,8,9
6   IDFJA   8,5,14,4,6
7   KDSFN   17,4,8,12,13,11,9,15,7,10,14,16,2,19,5,3,1
8   AKSKE   4,10,17,2,1,18,12,6,9,5
9   NAGJA   17,8
10  ODIJA   4,12,11,16,6,9,17
11  FKJSE   2,9,7,17,3,5,13,12,11,1,16,19,10,4,18,14,8,6
12  FDAKD   4,10,11,9,12,13,5,2,16,18,8,7,15,3
13  NFAKD   4,5,8,7,14,2,15
14  FJKAS   11,8,14,12,9,4,1,19,7,13,16,18,17,2,15,3,6
15  JDFKA   8,5,15,6
16  ATNFN   16,18,6,8
17  KAOJD   1,14,11,8,13,3,15,7,10
18  AODMK   8,19,17,15,3,12,7,1,14,2,11,6,16,18
19  FNAFJ   2,4,13,10,17,11,3,8,7,6,19,1
```

Comment: Could you tell in detail what exactly you want to replace? also try doing this `apply(data,1, function(x) gsub("to.replace", "replace.with", x))`

Comment: Depending on your desired output, either `fixed=T` or `perl=T` might fix the problem. I typically run thru 400k lines and 7000 patterns in 15 minutes

Comment: Please share the output of `dput(head(yourDataFrame))` and the desired output for that small sample.

Comment: So exactly what I'm looking to replace is the person's ID with a key values (aka 1:length(dataset)).  The specific difficulty here is that I need to search for and replace 300K+ values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving the problem in a round-about way.  Because each user had varying lengths of friends, I used the `dplyr` package to split up each row and apply a split function (using the `stringr` package) to each row: making a 'long' edgelist, and then I recombined the result back to the original format after converting the list to their factor equivalents.  The code for the recombine is quite messy, and I'm sure there may be a more efficient way to do it, but the code looks something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
# User defined split fuction
longedge <- function(df){
  user <- df$user_id
  cnx <- df$friends
  split <- as.data.frame(ifelse(cnx=="",NA,str_split(cnx,", ")))
  combine <- as.data.frame(cbind(user,split),stringAsFactors=FALSE)
  colnames(combine) <- c("user_id", "friend")
  return(combine)
}
# Creating long edgelist
edgelist <- edgelist %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  do(longedge(.)) %>%
  rbind()
# Convert to number
edgelist$friend <- as.numeric(as.factor(edgelist$friend))

# Create count of No. of connections
edgelist1 <- edgelist %>%
  group_by(user_id) %>%
  summarize(friend_count=n())

# Recreate 'wide' connection list
friend_list <- rep(NA,dim(edgelist1)[1])
for (i in 1:dim(edgelist1)[1]){
  if(i==1){j<-1}
  x <- j + edgelist1$friend_count[i]
  friend_list[i] <- as.character(edgelist$friend[j])
  j <- j+1
  while(j < x ){
    friend_list[i] <- paste(friend_list[i],edgelist$friend[j],sep=", ")
    j <- j+1
  }
}

# Recombine
edgelist1 <- cbind(edgelist1,friend_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not explicit code to solve your problem, but the strategy I would use.

If I read this correctly, Person is a unique identifier and Connection_list are your edges between people. Explicit conversion to integer is really not necessary if your values are factors and if you need numeric values for calculations further in your analysis stream, you can use the factor integer values.

First, I would convert Connection_list to multiple columns, discussed here for example: [Split column into multiple columns R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24100613/split-column-into-multiple-columns-r).

Then, after that is done and your columns are recognized as containing factor values,

```
aframe2 <- as.data.frame(lapply(aframe1, factor))
```

You should be able to retrieve the numeric values from those factors using something along the lines of `as.numeric(as.character(f))`.

Comment: The only issue with this method is that there are varying numbers of edges per person, where some edges even have no connections and others may have hundreds.