# Split text in columns of data frame based upon part of a pattern

Tags: r, strsplit

Using R I am trying to split text in a column with a specified delimite to always two new columns. An example data frame would be below:

```
repdf <- data.frame(a=c("abc(100)","def(95)","ghi(100)","j_(klm)(100)"),b=c("abc(100)","def(95)","ghi(100)","j_(klm)(100)"))
```

To put it simply, I want to split at every open bracket "(", but only if it is followed by a number, but without loosing the number. I.e. the desired result should look like:

```
a1      a2    b1      b2
abc     100)  abc     100)
def     95)   def     95)
ghi     100)  ghi     100)
j_(klm) 100)  j_(klm) 100)
```

I have tried to work with`splitstackshape::cSplit` and `stringr::str_split_fixed` to no avail.
`cSplit(repdf,c("a","b"),"(")` Splits at every "("

```
   a_1  a_2  a_3 b_1  b_2  b_3
1: abc 100)   NA abc 100)   NA
2: def  95)   NA def  95)   NA
3: ghi 100)   NA ghi 100)   NA
4:  j_ klm) 100)  j_ klm) 100)
```

`cSplit(repdf,c("a","b"),"\\(([0-9])",fixed=FALSE)` removes the first number, if it would be possible to use `\1` to add the capture to the second group that would be nice, but sadly it isn't.

```
       a_1 a_2     b_1 b_2
1:     abc 00)     abc 00)
2:     def  5)     def  5)
3:     ghi 00)     ghi 00)
4: j_(klm) 00) j_(klm) 00)
```

`as.data.frame(lapply(repdf,function(x)str_split_fixed(x,"\\(",n=2)))` allows me indeed to split only in 2 columns, but of course only takes the first match:

```
  a.1       a.2 b.1       b.2
1 abc      100) abc      100)
2 def       95) def       95)
3 ghi      100) ghi      100)
4  j_ klm)(100)  j_ klm)(100)
```

Comment: As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29726210/1655567), `extract` from [**`tidyr`**](https://rdrr.io/cran/tidyr/man/extract.html) may offer the necessary flexibility.

Comment: @Konrad while indeed that would be possible (e.g. `tidyr::extract(data=repdf,a,into=c('tax','prob'),"(.*)\\((?=\\d)(.*)",perl=TRUE)` it is not so easy to extrapolate to a data.frame with multiple columns.

Comment: @Konrad: you got me thinking.  While I initially got stuck on the non-standard evaluation version of `tidyr::extract` the standard evaluation function actually works quite elegant. I have added an answer below that uses it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is where a lookahead comes in handy... In essence we look for `(` that is followed by a digit `\\d` but the look ahead does not use the the digit for splitting.

```
do.call(cbind, lapply(repdf, function(x){
  do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(x), "\\((?=\\d)", perl = TRUE))
}))

# [,1]      [,2]   [,3]      [,4]  
# [1,] "abc"     "100)" "abc"     "100)"
# [2,] "def"     "95)"  "def"     "95)" 
# [3,] "ghi"     "100)" "ghi"     "100)"
# [4,] "j_(klm)" "100)" "j_(klm)" "100)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @Konrad's suggestions I found the following to work with `tidyr::extract`, but I needed to use its' standard evaluation version `tidyr::extract_`:

```
do.call(cbind, lapply(seq_along(repdf),
       function(df, i){
         tidyr::extract_(data=df[i], col = names(df[i]),
                  into=c(paste0("tax",i),paste0("prob",i)),
                  regex = "(.*)\\((?=\\d)(.*)",perl=TRUE)}, df=repdf))
```

The advantage here is that you can give the splitted columns predefined names (e.g. here `tax` and `prob`) which could be useful for downstream data wrangling. 
On the other hand, the interesting thing about the accepted answer is that when the number of colomns where the data is split into is not known in advance (or variable dependent upon the initial data frame column), it will still work like a charm.