# R function to parse

Tags: r, parsing

I am working with R and have a problem parsing a column in the dataset. The column name is called `read_data` with each row having values as follows:
"val":"O;P;Q8;S"}]
I want to parse this and be able to get O, P, Q8 and S in separate columns.
Could someone help me how to go about this?

The column has the  values from JSON as follows:

```
    "val":"O;P;Q8;S"}]
    "val":"P;V;I9;J"}]
    "val":"Z;A;G8;N"}]


    Expected Output:
    O P Q8 S
    P V I9 J
    Z A G8 N
```

Comment: Can you pleases show a small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: Is your data in tabular form? If so can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df[, colname])`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df[, colname], 20))`.

Comment: Also, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24100613/split-column-into-multiple-columns-r).

Comment: If it is a JSON, where is the `[{`

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  Please, follow this instructions for asking a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: any chance you can use something `jsonlite::read_json()` directly?

Comment: This is  the actual file given with one column. The value in the column has to be parsed as is to 4 new columns as shown.there is no [{ in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to extract the contents of with `fromJSON`, and read with `read.csv/read.table`

```
library(jsonlite)
read.table(text = paste(sapply(paste0('{', sub("\\]", "",  df1$col)),
    function(x) fromJSON(x)$val), collapse="\n"), header = FALSE, sep=";")
#  V1 V2 V3 V4
#1  O  P Q8  S
#2  P  V I9  J
#3  Z  A G8  N
```

---

Or another option is `base R`, where we extract the characters after the `:` and not a `}` (`[^}]+`), collapse the strings into a single string with `paste` after removing the double quotes (`"`) with `gsub`, then use `read.table/read.csv` by specifying the `sep` as `;` and `header` as `FALSE`

```
v1 <- paste(gsub('"', "", regmatches(df1$col, regexpr("(?<=:)[^}]+", 
    df1$col, perl = TRUE))), collapse="\n")
read.table(text = v1, header = FALSE, sep = ";")
#  V1 V2 V3 V4
#1  O  P Q8  S
#2  P  V I9  J
#3  Z  A G8  N
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(col = c("\"val\":\"O;P;Q8;S\"}]", "\"val\":\"P;V;I9;J\"}]", 
"\"val\":\"Z;A;G8;N\"}]")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I was still googling separate, apply functions etc to solve. I will check and learn the functions you have used. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @SandhyaSuresh  No problem.  I added some explanations.  Hope it would help in understanding